# Persistent H12 timeout error for all requests that run a database query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku

I have a Node.js app deployed using Heroku, as well as a Heroku Postgres database linked to it. The app also uses express and EJS to render pages.

I recently deployed an update to the app via a pull request into the master branch on GitHub (the master branch auto-deploys). After I did this, my app began giving me H12 timeout errors for seemingly all requests that run a DB query. If I load a page with no DB queries involved, the page will load just fine. There are no other errors being logged in the app console, just the request timeouts. No errors logged in the client-side browser console either.

After this happened, I reverted the deploy via GitHub using a revert pull request. So now the master branch in GitHub, which is also deployed to the live app currently, has the same code that it did prior to the update. However, I'm still getting the H12 error for all requests with DB queries, despite the fact that the code is the exact same as it was previously when everything worked just fine. I have tried restarting all dynos but that has not helped.

If I go to the Activity tab within Heroku, and revert to the old build version before the updates, then the site works as intended and the DB queries are processed normally. But as soon as I re-deploy the master branch with the original code, I'm right back to the H12 errors.

What's even more confusing is that I can run the app locally using the old version or the updated version, and everything works just fine. I can even run the app locally using the production database and it still works fine. None of the database requests are retrieving or otherwise processing significant amounts of data. When running locally, the pages all load nearly instantly.

I haven't changed any of the environment variables in Heroku, nor has the database login information been changed. I'm the only person who is accessing the live app at the moment, so the request timeouts are not being caused by other site traffic. I've even used New Relic to look at the site transactions, and I've verified that I'm the only one accessing the site.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be the issue here? I'm definitely at a complete loss.

The full repository can be accessed [here](https://github.com/KA-Challenge-Council/Bema).

Comment: If you are getting errors with the same code but freshly deployed then the heroku stack may have changed. I would also look at the build.log to see if it build fine: https://i.imgur.com/FRiaVCe.png Also compare the environment variables.

Comment: I'm running on the Heroku-18 stack, which is the same stack that was previously being used as far as I know. I tried upgrading to Heroku-20 and redeploying, but that did not help.

build.log is saying that the build was successful, and I'm not seeing anything else that indicates any errors. Environment variables are also the same. I've even copied and pasted into a diff check to make sure.

Comment: It appears the issue might have something to do with node versioning. When I revert to the working deploy in Heroku, the app builds using Node 12.20.1. However, when I deploy a new branch it builds using 14.15.4. Still, nothing in the database connection code has been changed in between those deploys, so I still don't understand why the DB connection is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Heroku has changed their **default node.js deployment version** from **12.20.1** to **14.15.4** in the last few days.

Explicitly **[specifying your node version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version)**, by adding the following **"engines"** section in your **package.json** file, should resolve your issue:

```
{
  "name": "Contest-judging-tool",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "description": "An open source tool used to judge official contests on Khan Academy",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.20.1"
  },
  "scripts": ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! When I deploy with that code everything seems to be working okay. Any idea why the app isn't working on the newer version of node (14.15.4)? When I deploy on the new version, the app still builds and is able to run, but all DB queries do not work. Nothing has changed with the DB code or otherwise basic structure of the app. Is there something major that I need to update?

Comment: There is a known issue with node.js 14.0.0 and above which requires pg package version 8.0.3 or higher in order to connect correctly to a postgres database and not timeout. Unless you are explicitly specifying a package dependency for the pg package, Heroku would have installed pg 7.18.2, introducing the connectivity problem. More info on the postgres connectivity issue for version 14.0.0 can be found here [https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2180](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2180)